# Rails 5 query in related models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

- 1st model is `Encuesta` it has many Preguntas
- 2nd model is `Pregunta` belongs to `Encuesta`, among other attributes it has one called `date`

In my `PreguntasController` I have my method `index`

```
def index   
    @preguntas = @encuesta.preguntas 
end
```

So my variable `@preguntas` contains all the preguntas that belongs to a specific `Encuesta`, and this is working fine.

Now I want to select all the preguntas that belong to specific encuestas by "date"(attribute of `Pregunta`). this is my attempt, but it is not working:

```
 @preguntas = @encuesta.preguntas.where(date: paramas[:date])
```

How should I build the query correctly?? thanks

Comment: Could you pleas post the result of running `Pregunta.columns_hash["date"].type`?

Answer (score 0):

First lets see something about `Date`. Working with dates could be a really extense 
topic (and I know just the very basics) but you are trying to do (something like) this:

```
t = Pregunta.where(date: "2017-03-09")
  Pregunta Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "Preguntas".* FROM "Preguntas" WHERE "Preguntas"."date" = ?  [["date", "2017-03-09"]]
=> []
```

If you check in your DB, you will probably find that your date is a timestamp. In you project directory type:

```
$ rails db
> select * from preguntas;
```

Or any other `select` that shows you a record, and you will find that the value is in thie form:

```
2017-03-09 13:24:42.452593
```

Now, is easier to see why you are not getting any record, is because you are missing the exact value of the field. Now try this,
with one value that you see in the `select * from preguntas`:

```
# replace with one date of your DB!!!
t = Pregunta.where(date: "2017-03-09 13:24:42.480866") 
  Pregunta Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "Preguntas".* FROM "Preguntas" WHERE "Preguntas"."date" = ?  [["date", "2017-03-09 13:24:42.480866"]]
=> [#<Pregunta:0x00000002d41258
id: 3,
field1: "now",
field2: "body",
... >]
```

Finally, What you want to search (probably) are the dates in that particular day, so try something like:

```
t = Pregunta.where(date: @date.beginning_of_day..@date.end_of_day)
  Pregunta Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "Preguntas".* FROM "Preguntas" WHERE ("Preguntas"."date" BETWEEN '2017-03-09 03:00:00.000000' AND '2017-03-10 02:59:59.999999')
=> [#<Pregunta:0x000000021a2e88 id: 3, field1: "now", field1: "body", date: Thu, 09 Mar 2017 10:24:42 BRT -03:00>,
```

Where `@date` is the day you need to search (created with something similar to `@date = Date.new(2017, 3, 9)`)

Here you can see the Select Statement that it is a `BETWEEN` of the dates `'2017-03-09 03:00:00.000000'` and `'2017-03-10 02:59:59.999999'`